# How can I determine the number of threads Matlab is using?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, process, pid, ps

When I run simply `"matlab"`, maxNumCompThreads returns 4.

When I run `"matlab -singleCompThread"`, maxNumCompThreads returns 1.

However in both instances, `ps uH p <PID> | wc -l` (which I picked up from another question on SO to determine the number of threads a process is using) returns 35.

What gives?  Can somebody explain to me what the 35 represents, and whether or not I can trust maxNumCompThreads as indicating that Matlab is only using one thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of threads used by MATLAB for computation (`maxNumCompThreads`) is different from the number of threads MATLAB.exe uses to manage its internal functions: the interpreter, memory manager, command line, who knows what else.  If you were writing MATLAB, imagine the number of threads required to manage the various ongoing, independent tasks. Perhaps have a look at the Octave or FreeMat code to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the threads you see are used by the JVM that MATLAB launches. You could try the flag "-nojvm" to cut things down further. Obviously, without the JVM, functionality is very limited. "-singleCompThread" limits only the threads used by numeric computation such as MATLAB's intrinsic multithreading as well as threads used by external libraries such as MKL and FFTW.